# Array of objects: return only objects (and children) where attribute matches

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, linq.js

I have an array with several "levels" or children. I would like to create a new array of objects where archived===false so that no archived objects are listed.

So this...

```
var arr = [
    {"id":1, "archived":false,"children":[
        {"id":1,"archived":true, "subs":[
            {"id":1,"archived":true},
            {"id":2,"archived":true},
            {"id":3,"archived":true}
        ]},
        {"id":2,"archived":false, "subs":[
            {"id":1,"archived":false},
            {"id":2,"archived":false},
            {"id":3,"archived":true}
        ]}
    ]},
    {"id":2, "archived":true,"children":[
        {"id":1,"archived":true, "subs":[
            {"id":1,"archived":true},
            {"id":2,"archived":true},
            {"id":3,"archived":true}
        ]},
        {"id":2,"archived":true, "subs":[
            {"id":1,"archived":true},
            {"id":2,"archived":true},
            {"id":3,"archived":true}
        ]}
    ]},
    {"id":3, "archived":false,"children":[
        {"id":1,"archived":false, "subs":[
            {"id":1,"archived":true},
            {"id":2,"archived":false},
            {"id":3,"archived":true}
        ]},
        {"id":2,"archived":false, "subs":[
            {"id":1,"archived":false},
            {"id":2,"archived":false},
            {"id":3,"archived":false}
        ]}
    ]}
];
```

Becomes...

```
var arr = [
    {"id":1, "archived":false,"children":[
        {"id":2,"archived":false, "subs":[
            {"id":1,"archived":false},
            {"id":2,"archived":false}
        ]}
    ]},
    {"id":3, "archived":false,"children":[
        {"id":1,"archived":false, "subs":[
            {"id":2,"archived":false}
        ]},
        {"id":2,"archived":false, "subs":[
            {"id":1,"archived":false},
            {"id":2,"archived":false},
            {"id":3,"archived":false}
        ]}
    ]}
];
```

I've tried combinations of map, reduce, filter, and grep...but I probably do not have the order right, etc. I know I could just loop through each level, but I can't get it just right.

It would be great to have this contained in a linq.js enumerable array or in jQuery.

[Non-working Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksumarine/8fuj4077/1/)

Comment: Have you looked into Array.prototype.map?

Comment: I did, but I am having trouble getting the correct children throughout the "levels"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A well crafted function to handle recursion could make doing this with linq.js fairly simple to do.  This in particular doesn't necessarily need linq.js, but it keeps it simple.

```
function isNotArchived(childrenName, childrenFilter) {
  return function (e) {
    var filtered = e.Where("!$.archived");
    if (childrenName && childrenFilter) {
      return filtered.Select(function (c) {
        var result = { id: c.id, archived: c.archived };
        result[childrenName] = $.Enumerable.From(c[childrenName])
          .Let(childrenFilter)
          .ToArray();
        return result;
      });
    }
    return filtered;
  };
}
var filtered = $.Enumerable.From(arr)
  .Let(isNotArchived("children",
    isNotArchived("subs",
      isNotArchived()
    )
  ))
  .ToArray();
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ed7ppmxc/1/)

Comment: This is really nice, however, the code is missing an archived:true in one of the "sub" arrays: https://jsfiddle.net/ksumarine/ed7ppmxc/

Comment: Why should they be included when the parent is excluded? The way you have your inputs and outputs set up, the parent object must exist. If you're specifically trying to search for any object that is not archived at any level, then you need to change how you want your outputs to be. And with the current structure you have (it must match the existing object), it just won't work.

Comment: No, I was saying that the output from your code contains an item that is archived, when it should exclude all archived items.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood.  I see what you mean, it'll need a little tweak.

Answer (score 1):

This requires recursion.

Change your code to include a function that works along the lines of this pseudo code as:

```
function filterRecursive(array, filterFunction){
    for(obj in array){
        if(obj.children){
            obj.children = filterRecursive(obj.children, filterFunction);
        }
        obj = filterFunction(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not exactly sure how to implement this. Maybe I've been staring at all my code too much.

Comment: @ksumarine, it's not your fault. Gravityplanx's answer needed to show _how_ to implement it, not just what kind of function.

Comment: @Mirabilis:  SO is a resource to gain a better understanding of coding practices, not a place to ask other people to write code for you.  My answer explains what is missing from the provided code, it's still up to ksumarine to write it to fit his own needs.

Comment: @ksumarine:  The trick is that you need to call `filterRecursive` **within itself**, passing in the children array instead of the parent array.  You can't do what you are asking with a single pass through the filter.  Instead, you need to do it once through for the parent level, and then re-call the function for each array of children.  Specifically, in the pseudo code provided, notice how line 4 calls the function that it exists within, but acting on the children.

Comment: @gravityplanx I'm not asking anyone to write code for me, but it would help to have an explanation of what you're trying to show me. EDIT: wrote this before you provided an explanation...thank you!

Comment: @gravityplanx notice how the child arrays change from "children" to "subs" so I have to account for that also.

Comment: Yup.  Just repeat the `if` clause for both possible locations of the children arrays.

Answer (score 1):

My solution with no recursion and assuming the depth and structure of the initial object is fixed:

```js
var arr = [
  {
    "id": 1, "archived": false, "children": [
      {
        "id": 1, "archived": true, "subs": [
          {"id": 1, "archived": true},
          {"id": 2, "archived": true},
          {"id": 3, "archived": true}
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2, "archived": false, "subs": [
          {"id": 1, "archived": false},
          {"id": 2, "archived": false},
          {"id": 3, "archived": true}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2, "archived": true, "children": [
      {
        "id": 1, "archived": true, "subs": [
          {"id": 1, "archived": true},
          {"id": 2, "archived": true},
          {"id": 3, "archived": true}
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2, "archived": true, "subs": [
          {"id": 1, "archived": true},
          {"id": 2, "archived": true},
          {"id": 3, "archived": true}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3, "archived": false, "children": [
      {
        "id": 1, "archived": false, "subs": [
          {"id": 1, "archived": true},
          {"id": 2, "archived": false},
          {"id": 3, "archived": true}
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2, "archived": false, "subs": [
          {"id": 1, "archived": false},
          {"id": 2, "archived": false},
          {"id": 3, "archived": false}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

function checkChildrensForFalse(elements) {
  var retVal = [];
  for (var eleChildIndex in elements) {
    if (elements[eleChildIndex].archived == false) {
      var tmpObj = {
        'id': elements[eleChildIndex].id,
        'archived': elements[eleChildIndex].archived,
        'subs': []
      }
      for (var eleSubIndex in elements[eleChildIndex].subs) {
        if (elements[eleChildIndex].subs[eleSubIndex].archived == false) {
          tmpObj.subs.push(elements[eleChildIndex].subs[eleSubIndex]);
        }
      }
      if (tmpObj.subs !== []) {
        retVal.push(tmpObj);
      }
    }
  }
  return retVal;
}

arr = arr.map(function (currentValue, index, array) {
  if (currentValue.archived == false) {
    var ele = checkChildrensForFalse(currentValue.children);
    if (ele !== []) {
      return {'id': currentValue.id, 'archived': currentValue.archived, 'children': ele};
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}).filter(function (item) {
  return item != null
});

/**********
         * The result formatted is:
        var result = [{
            "id": 1, "archived": false,"children": [{
                "id": 2, "archived": false, "subs": [
                    {"id": 1, "archived": false}, {"id": 2, "archived": false}]
            }]
        }, {"id": 3, "archived": false, "children": [
            {"id": 1, "archived": false, "subs": [{"id": 2, "archived": false}]},
            {"id": 2, "archived": false, "subs": [{"id": 1, "archived": false}, {"id": 2, "archived": false}, {"id": 3, "archived": false}]
            }]
        }];
         */
document.write('<p>' + JSON.stringify(arr) + '</p>')
```